# Static variable in Python set value from another class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have class in file `api.py` that contains property:

```
class API(object):
    api_key = ''
    def add_advert(self):
        print(self.api_key)
```

In another class I use import class above:

```
import api
api = api.API()
```

Then in class I try to write value into property `api_key`:

```
api.api_key = 'NEW VALUE'
```

So, when I call another method from `api` class:

```
api.add_advert()
```

It does not return me new value for `api_key`:

```
def add_advert(self):
    print(self.api_key)
```

**My final code is:**

```
import controller.api

apiClass = controller.api.API()
```

When I try to set:

```
apiClass.api_key = 'NEW VALUE'
```

It gives me :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'api_key'

Comment: `api.api_key = 'NEW VALUE'` assigne `NEW VALUE` to the instance (`api`) not to a class (`API`) attribute.

Comment: Why I have created instance `api = api.API()`

Comment: Yes, and after that assignment that instance (and that instance alone) has attribute `api_key` of value `NEW VALUE`. Class `API` and all other possible instance are unaffected by that assignment (which happened to that one instance).

Comment: there is no static property in class Python or all properties are static by default?

Comment: Python is a highly dynamic language, and doesn't have notions of "static" like in other languages. I would suggest setting the API key during initialization (i.e. in the `__init__` method of the `API` class), rather than relying on class attributes.

Comment: I can not do this, I need change this property outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion. Actually in its most recent form if you run:

```
>>> from api import API
>>> myapi = API()
>>> myapi.add_advert()

>>> myapi.api_key='xxx'
>>> myapi.add_advert()
xxx
```

Which sounds like what you wanted. So was there just a typo? Or is there a bit missing in the question?

---

To the wider question. No, there isn't a static class attribute (or variable) as such... but behavior of mutable objects sort of gives you that behavior known from other languages (and occasionally confuses heck out of people when they accidentally stumble upon it). With:

```
class C:
    mutable_attr = []
```

You can try:

```
>>> c1 = C()
>>> c2 = C()
>>> c1.mutable_attr.append('foo')
>>> c2.mutable_attr
['foo']
```

Indeed they all refer to the same object (instance of list).

```
>>> c1.mutable_attr is c2.mutable_attr is C.mutable_attr
True
```

However, assign directly to an attribute (instead of manipulating that object), the "magic" is gone:

```
>>> c1.mutable_attr = ['bar']
>>> c2.mutable_attr
['foo']
```

---

This is tangential, but even more fun with functions. If you use mutable type as a default value, it's assigned to a variable when the function is defined (not called) and every time you call it falling back to that default, it's still that one object:

```
def f(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    print(x)
```

And then:

```
>>> f()
[1]
>>> f(['a'])
['a', 1]
>>> f()
[1, 1]  # back to the original (default) object for appending
```

---

In all honesty. You better avoid either... because it really can get confusing and surprising esp. when someone else gets to work on your code. It essentially breaks encapsulation of your object and impact of change goes beyond what is immediately obvious. A linter will flag it as a problem too. ;)

Comment: But now that `apiClass` cannot be an instance of `API` from top of your questions. Something else went awry. What is `controller.api.API`? Does perhaps `controller.api` need an `importlib.reload()`? Because if I run those two last lines using `API` from top of the question, all is well.

Comment: `controller.api.API()` controller it is directory, `api` it is file and `API()` it is name of class

Comment: Yes, I am dubious regarding content of the latter with respect to the former two. Because If it cannot be identical to the `API` you included in your question (or your running Python session is not reflective of that).

Comment: I dont understand problem and how to solve, why Python so unconvinient

Comment: Don't give up... Python can be a great tool. Just like using any tool, it gets better and easier with practice.

Comment: My import is: `import controller.api`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't make your variable name shadow the import name of your file. Change the `api` variable to something different like `api_var`. Then, Use `api_var.api_key` or if you import the API class, `API.api_key`. You need to refer to either the instance or the class to get the class/static variable. Python doesn't magically know what namespace you're referring to.